# UISplitViewController is removing my toolbar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a UISplitViewController which contains UINavigationControllers on the left and right side. The left hand navigation bar works fine, and I can see the navigation on the right hand side. I'm trying to push two ViewControllers onto the right hand side, defined as segues in IB. No matter what I try, the right hand toolbars just get hidden when the app runs. I've even tried dragging a UIToolbar onto the middle of the view and not connecting it anywhere, and it's still just removed when the app runs. Is this intended behaviour? Am I forced to use the bottom toolbar if I need a toolbar in a split view?